# Google reports mobile issues for directory listing page, will it hurt the rest of my site?

Tags: google-search-console, mobile, directory-listing

We have some mobile-friendly issues affecting `/domains/.well-known/`

This page simply displays:

> Index of /domains/.well-known
>   Parent Directory (a link)
>   pki-validation/ (a link)

Do the mobility issues for this page affect the site overall? i.e. will there be any penalty that affects the site, or is the penalty applied to the page only?

Should I add this page to the blocked pages in robots.txt?

Comment: Disallowing that directory in robots.txt could be harmful.  The contents of that directory are meant to be consumed by validation bots.   It's not clear that the validations will work if bots are disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile-issues that affect a single page, affect that page, not the entire site.

However, `/domains/.well-known/` presumably doesn't have anything to do with your public facing website anyway? The `.well-known` and `pki-validation` directories are used when SSL certs are auto-renewed - to *validate* access.

Why do you have directory listings enabled? (You probably should not.) If directory listings are disabled then the search engines would receive a 403 Forbidden response and you wouldn't be getting this message reported in GSC in the first place.

In other words, include this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If you have certain directories that you want to see a server generated directory listing, then enable this on a per-directory basis.